# Batch find executable that can be anywhere (any drive or folder) and deliver its full path

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I am trying to find a file named "**ABC.exe"**. The script below gets the result I want, but:

1. It is unnecessarily complicated
2. It finds the file and full path but keeps on running forever
3. It is dependent on the user input

```
    @echo off & setlocal enabledelayedexpansion 

    for /f "tokens=*delims= " %%f in ('mountvol^|find /i ":\"')do set _drv=!_drv!, %%f
    set "_drv=!_drv: =!" & echo/ & set /p "_arq= Inform the file name: " & set _lf=^

    <nul 2>nul & set "_msg= Analysing the file variables" & cls & set "_input=%~1"
    cls & set "_drv=!_drv:~1!" & set "_sys=%windir%\system32" & call :~[ && goto :?)

    :^[
    echo/!_lf!Searching for file %~1 in drives: !_drv!^... !_lf!
    for /f "tokens=*delims= " %%f in ('!_sys!\mountvol^|find /i ":\"')do (
         for /f "tokens=*delims= " %%F in ('cd /d %%f ^& cd\ ^& !_sys!\where /r .\ "!_%%/!" 2^>nul') do (
             set "_%2=%%~nxF" && set "_path_%2=%%~dpF" && set "_full_%2=%%~fF" && echo/ !_msg! !_%%/!^...
             echo/!_lf! File name: !_%%~/! !_lf! Path result: !_path_%%/! &echo/ Complete Path: !_full_%%/! & exit /b))

    :~[
    (for %%/ in (arq,input)do call :^[ "!_%%/!" %%/) && exit /b 

    :?)
    echo/!_lf! new actions below this line !!!..
```

I need help to make it elegant and functional. Basically:

1. Find "ABC.exe" that can be anywhere (drives or folders)
2. Should not be at the mercy of the user input
3. Has to simply yield the result "The full path is ..." or "file not found"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following only requires the search file to be defined prior to initial use.
It will locate all available drives using `wmic`, then search each of those drives using `where`, returning all matches to a value indexed by the drive it was located in.

Values are checked using a `for /F` loop on the Set command in conjunction with the index variable.

```bat
@echo off
rem // Allow modification of variables during () Code Blocks
    Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    Set D#=& Rem // Index variable for the number of Drives
Rem // Process wmic output to return all available Drives to an Array
    For /F "Tokens=1,2 Delims==" %%D in ('wmic logicaldisk get name /format:value') Do (
        If /I "%%D"=="Name" For %%L in (%%E) Do (
            Set /A D#+=1
            Set "Drive[!D#!]=%%L"
    )   )
    Set Found=
Rem // Define the file to be searched for
    Set SearchFile=& Rem // DEFINE SEARCHFILE.EXT
Rem // Search the Available Drives using the Array values, Build Array of Matches
    For /F "Tokens=2 delims==" %%L in ('Set Drive[') Do (
        Set "DL=%%~L"
        Set "DL=!DL:~0,1!"
        Set "!DL!M#=0"
        For /F "Delims=" %%P in ('where /R %%L\ !SearchFile! 2^> Nul') Do (
            Set /A "!DL!M#+=1"
            For %%i in (!DL!) Do Set "Match[!DL!:!%%iM#!]=%%~P"
        )
        For /F "Tokens=1,2 Delims==" %%M in ('Set Match[!DL! 2^> Nul') Do (
            Echo/%%N
            Set Found=1
    )   )
    If not Defined Found Echo/No File Match.
Pause
```